# Javascript-Google App Script-TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código en una hoja de cálculo en Google Docs. La idea es mostrar un registro con datos de otras hojas, pero al ejecutar obtengo el error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". ¿Que podría hacer?

```
function processData(sheetData){

 var transpose = m => m[0].map((x,i) => m.map(x => x[i]))
 
 var data = sheetData.map(x=>x.slice(0,422))
 
 data[1] = data[1].map((l => (v, i) => l = v === ''  ? l : v)());
 var transposedData = transpose(data)
 transposedData[0] = transposedData[0].map((l => (v, i) => l = v === ''  ? l : v)());
 data = transpose(transposedData)
 
 var dataFilterProjects = data.filter(fila=> fila.slice(2,).map(j=> (j!='') ? 1 : 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)!=0)
 var dataFilterDays = transpose(transpose(dataFilterProjects).filter(fila=> fila.slice(4,).map(j=> (j!='') ? 1 : 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)!=0))
 var dataTotalFilter = dataFilterDays.filter(fila=> fila[1]!= 'Total')
 
 return dataTotalFilter
}
```

Comment: ¿que es **m**?  No lo veo definido ni pasado como parametro

Comment: tienes varios `map` en el código. Cual de esos te saca error? aquel que te esté sacando error, es porque la variable no está definida. Debes revisar porque no está definida. Revisa si te falta meter alguna condición antes de hacer el `map`